# Google maps API geolocation + radar places search

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use both Geolocation and Places from the google maps API to display a map (at my location) with the nearest places around me. The two examples work seperately but not together.

Can anyone tell me why there is a problem with this? am I overwriting the map with another or doing something else wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyA93l5zPyIvGB7oYGqzLSk28r5XuIs2Do8
&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
var map;
var service;
var marker;
var pos;


function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);


      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Located'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  var request = {
      location:pos,
      radius:500,
      types: ['store']
  };

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request,callback);

  function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

*EDIT*

Moved the code now so it looks like - Has not fixed the problem of location being undefined.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        var request = {
      location:pos,
      radius:500,
      types: ['store']
  };

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request,callback);
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);


      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Located'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });'
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: The map shows up and it geolocates in my browser, however the radar search places do not show up at all let alone locally to the area it has geolocated. For reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search is the example I want to implement but instead of a set location I want it to be dependent on the users geolocation. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: So you can see the live version - https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gW3AYRbRMoYU5RaHpNS2ZEY3c/energizemap.html

error - Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify location.

Comment: Your main problem is that geolocation is asynchronous, you need to use the returned position inside the callback when it is available (where you call map.setCenter).  Also, your map doesn't do anything useful in the error case (where geolocation is disabled) other than show an infowindow in Siberia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of async call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` which returns immediately, `location` property of request is undefined. Call to

```
service.nearbySearch(request,callback);
```

complains that location is missing. And that is true because `pos` is not set at that moment.

You have to move this part of code:

```
        var request = {
            location:pos,
            radius:500,
            types: ['store']
        };

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request,callback);
```

to

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    ...
            map.setCenter(pos);
```

and make variable `infoWindow` global.

This is changed `initialize()` function:

```
var map;
var service;
var marker;
var pos;
var infowindow;


function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    console.log(map);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Located'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);

            var request = {
                location:pos,
                radius:500,
                types: ['store']
            };

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request,callback);
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log('after / to createMarker');
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Anto, can you specify what I need to change?

Comment: Also i made infowindow global

Comment: Solved it! Thankyou, I did what you said but must have deleted a section and just noticed.