# Get lat and lon that are in a 5km radius from a given lat and lon

Tags: javascript, instagram

I want to get the lat and lon that can be in a 5km radius from a given lat and lon, I'm using the instagram api to search for pics with a certain tag and the filter by the place they are, some pictures have the location object with the lat and lon of the pic, what I want to do is only get the pics that have  the same lat and lon from a lat and lon I give or that are in a 5km radius of those I give, Thank you!

Comment: I'd start with the API documentation http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/

Comment: I've read the documentation, I know i have the location endpoint but I want to look for pics with a certain tag in a given position and they don't let you do that, I've been told repeatedly that I have to search by geolocation and then filter by tag or vice versa.

Comment: In that case then I'd suggest posting your existing code and explain where you're having trouble. As it stands this question is likely to be closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410902/google-maps-api-geolocation-radar-places-search) would get you on the right track.

It explains how to search within a radius of a point and display that, but only return a specific type of return. This should be enough to get you going!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search) call to get photos posted within 5km of a lat/lng:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat={LAT}&lng={LNG}&distance=5000&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Here is an implementation of this type of search: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

Comment: Yes I know how to search by location with the api, this was not the question, the question was, for example I have lat 28.82137, lon -16.1238, I want to get all posible latitudes and longitudes in a 5km radius