# google maps geolocation and places issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to do a geolocation which will add place markers for car wash in near area. 
I got the code for showing locations based on static long and lat but I need to add geolocation to it. Please help me.

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    types: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps geolocation, need to add google places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339292/google-maps-geolocation-need-to-add-google-places)

Comment: You have posted both sides of the question.  Where is the code you wrote to combine those two functions?  What problems are you having doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps API geolocation + radar places search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410902/google-maps-api-geolocation-radar-places-search)